# boiling of the Glosters

Tags: meaning-in-context

The **boiling of the Glosters** in the clouds as they leapt the sky in one, chased by their own din.

What is 'Glosters' here, and what is boiling of Glosters mean?

Thanks.

Comment: Where does this come from? What is the context? That is a very strange phrase. Glosters spelt like that commonly refers to the [Gloucestershire Regiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloucestershire_Regiment) from the UK but it doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: Haroldo Conti, Argentinian author.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haroldo_Conti This is fiction (the English title is Southeaster). Voting to close as it’s a literature question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s about fiction.

Answer (score 2):

The [Gloster aircraft company](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloster_Aircraft_Company) produced military aircraft for the British government in both world wars, in particular the [Bristol F28](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bristol_F.2_Fighter)  reconnaissance and fighter aircraft in WW1 and the [Gloster Meteor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloster_Meteor) the allies only jet fighter in WW2.

Depending on the period of the book "Glosters" could refer to almost any product of the company. "The boiling of the Glosters" would refer (poetically) to either or both of the disturbance of the air as the stick of planes took off or the visual effect of complex movement on the observer (compare with "the boiling of the waters" referring to waves or the disturbance of water by sea creatures, boats, or submarines). "Chased by their own din" then becomes a reference to the sound of the aircraft.

**EDIT:**
As the book identified by Xanne in a comment was published in the 1962 the reference is probably to Gloster Meteors which continued to be produced after the war, could well have been sold to the Argentine government in the 50s and with which Conti, as a pilot, would have been familiar.

Comment: Argentina ordered 100 Gloster Meteor F4s in 1947, 50 ex-RAF and 50 newly built. They remained in service until 1970.

Comment: Haroldo Conti disappeared in 1976, and was probably murdered by the 1976 - 1983 Argentinian dictatorship.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Presumably the Gloster Meteors were replaced by the French-built Mirages that caused so much damage to British shipping in the Falklands campaign.

Comment: The Mirages indeed replaced the Meteors after 1970 in Argentine Air Force service, as interceptors. It was Argentine Navy Dassault Super Etendards, delivered in 1981, and used in the naval attack role firing Exocet missiles, that did so much damage to British shipping in 1982.

Comment: And we had the Avro Vulcan.